# Bug en los datos estadísticos de elecciones

Tags: bug, elecciones, página-de-elecciones

Quería ver sí alguien me logra explicar el porque de que la cantidad de personas que visitaron el sitio durante las elecciones es menor que las personas que visitaron la página de elecciones.

Imagino que será un bug o algún error a la hora de la ejecución de los Querys que usaron para publicar dicha información.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Será que algunos llegaron directamente a través de la notificación a https://es.stackoverflow.com/election/1 sin pasar por otra página de SOes?

Comment: @Rubén o que una visita al sitio no cuenta como "visita" hasta que realiza alguna otra acción, pero una visita a la página de elecciones sí... De todas formas, estamos intentando adivinar. Si no está en MSE, sólo un dev puede responderlo.

Comment: En ese caso @Mariano, ¿Una acción no sería el visitar la página de elecciones?

Comment: @RandallSandoval probablemente no. Pero no lo sé